# Sum over Posterior Predictive Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian

I am confused about the posterior predictive distribution.

This is from Murphy's Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective. According to the example set in Chapter 3, the posterior predictive distribution is: 
$$p(\tilde{x} \in C \mid D) = \displaystyle\sum_{h} p(y = 1 \mid \tilde{x}, h) p(h \mid D) $$ I believe $y=f(x\in C) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \quad \text{if } x \in C\\
    0 & \quad \text{if } x \notin C\\
  \end{cases}
$ although it's not mentioned in the text.
Should the posterior predictive distribution sum to 1? $$ \displaystyle\sum_{\tilde{x}} p(\tilde{x} \in C \mid D) = 1$$ or is the interpretation that $$ p(\tilde{x} \in C \mid D) + p(\tilde{x} \notin C \mid D) = 1$$

Comment: While I am not mathematician/statistician enough I believe that using the [*indicator function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) might have given nicer notation than using $y=f(x \in C)$?

Comment: I was just reading this text, and the sudden introduction of $y$ also confused me.

Answer (score 1):

The last interpretation should be correct. My understanding of the [*posterior predictive distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution) is, that you are looking for the probability of (yet) unobserved data $\tilde{x}$. What you have here is some model with a parameter $h$ and previously observed data which have been processed into a *posterior probability distribution* for $h$.

It should hold that:

\begin{align*}
p(\tilde{x}|D) = \sum_{h}p(\tilde{x},h|D) = \sum_{h}p(\tilde{x}|h)\,p(h|D)
\end{align*}

Here $p(\tilde{x}|D)$ is giving the conditional probability for all possible values of $\tilde{x}$. Probability theory states that:

\begin{align*}
p(\tilde{x} \in C|D) + p(\tilde{x}\notin C|D) = 1
\end{align*}